# Report abuse YT channel via API call

Tags: python, youtube-api

I have read youtube API docs and I am unable to find how to report a channel. I have found only endpoint responsible for reporting videos https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/reportAbuse. Is it possible to create function like mine, but to report not videos, but channel based on its id?

```
def yt_report_livestream(video_id):
    URL = f"https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/reportAbuse?alt=json"
    payload = {
        "videoId": video_id,
        "comments": "Scam",
        "reasonId": "S",
        "secondaryReasonId": "31",
    }
    payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
    response = requests.post(
        url=URL,
        data=payload_json,
        headers=OAUTH_HEADER,
        proxies=proxyDict,
        verify=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no endpoint for reporting a channel only one for reporting a video.

May i suggest that you post a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)